# Unable to upgrade/update iPad 2 from iOS 5.1.1 (to iOS to 9.3)

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update

I have an iPad 2 (MC769LL/A) that is running iOS 5.1.1. I need to update the OS. The device is telling me there's an update for 9.3, but I'm getting an error saying unable to verify the update because I'm no longer connected to the internet.

Before you even suggest it, I did all these things mentioned here (and everywhere else): https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7506344?tstart=0. Is this iPad in un-update-able hell? Is there some way I can manually update it to a lower version than 9 as a stepping stone?

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I resolved this problem, or rather, iTunes *decided* to resolve this problem for me after some hesitation; it finally prompted me to update the device (after telling me it wasn't supported -_-). So if you're in my boat and exhausted all of those "turn it off and back on"-esque options, hopefully fidgeting with iTunes grants you the opportunity to update.